# Express: Argument of type 'ParsedQs' is not assignable to parameter of type XXXX

Tags: typescript, express

Here I have a function and an interface that describes its only argument:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
}

function makeData(data: SomeInterface): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve(data)
}
```

This function is used in an express application as a controller:

```
router.get('/file', (req, res) => {
    makeData(req.query).then(data => res.status(200).send(data))
})
```

TypeScript underlines req.query when it is passed in makeData and says:

> Argument of type 'ParsedQs' is not assignable to parameter of type
> SomeInterface

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly cast req.query to your interface, try this instead:

```
router.get('/file', (req, res) => {
    const query = req.query as unknown as SomeInterface;
    makeData(query).then(data => res.status(200).send(data))
})
```